# Can I mmap a file with length greater than the size of the file?

Tags: c, file, segmentation-fault, mmap

```
void *mmap(void *addr, size_t length, int prot, int flags, int fd, off_t offset);
```

I do not understand exactly how `mmap` works when using the `MAP_PRIVATE` flag. Can I pass a `length` greater than the size of file `fd` to `mmap`? After doing so, can I write and read the memory that exceeds the size of the file but is within `length`?

I am writing some code which calculates the MD5 of files. I have decided to write functions which only manipulate data as a `void*` and `size_t len`, instead of using the standard library stream functions. Before, I was using `malloc` and copying the files into some malloc'ed memory before using them, but that proved to be quite slow for large files, and quite stupid once I found out about `mmap`.

The problem that I am dealing with is that before calculating the MD5 of any data, [some padding and information is appended to the data that will be hashed.](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1321#page-3) With the previous solution of `malloc` I would just calculate how much data needs to be appended and then `realloc` and write. Now, I am calculating beforehand how much data needs to be appended and passing this increased length to `mmap`. On small files this works fine, but on large files trying to write to the addresses outside of the size of the file results in a segmentation fault.

This is vaguely what I'm trying to do:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>


// The Data + length struct
struct data{
        void* s;
        size_t len;
};

//mmap on opened file descriptor into a data struct
struct data* data_ffile(int fd)
{
        struct data* ret = malloc(sizeof(struct data));

        //Get the length of the file
        struct stat desc;
        fstat(fd, &desc);
        ret->len = (size_t)desc.st_size;

        //Calculate the length after appending
        size_t new_len =  ret->len + 1;
        if((new_len % 64) > 56)
                new_len += (64 * 2) - (new_len % 64);
        else if((new_len % 64) <= 56)
                new_len += 64 - (new_len % 64);

        //Map the file with the increased length
        ret->s = mmap(NULL, new_len, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
                      MAP_PRIVATE, fd, 0);

        if(ret->s == MAP_FAILED) exit(-1);

        return ret;
}

//Append a character to the mmap'ed data
void data_addchar(struct data* w, unsigned char c)
{
        ((char*)w->s)[w->len++] = c;
        return;
}

void md5_append(struct data* md)
{
        data_addchar(md, 0x80);

        while((md->len % 64) != 56){
                data_addchar(md, (char)0);
        }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
        int fd = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);
        struct data* in = data_ffile(fd);
        close(fd);

        md5_append(in);
}
```

Do I have basic misunderstanding of `mmap`?

Comment: @kaylum I have edited the question to made the code example compilable. (I have omitted error handling and memory handling for the sake of brevity and readibility). This example reproduces the issue that I'm having which is a segfault on `data_addchar` with a large file. The file I'm using is the [Fedora 31 netinstall ISO](https://mirrors.rit.edu/fedora/fedora/linux/releases/31/Server/x86_64/iso/Fedora-Server-netinst-x86_64-31-1.9.iso) (650MB)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can I pass a length greater than the size of file fd to mmap? After doing so, can I write and read the memory that exceeds the size of the file but is within length?

This is all documented in the mmap POSIX [specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/mmap.html):

> The system shall always zero-fill any partial page at the end of an
>   object. Further, the system shall never write out any modified
>   portions of the last page of an object which are beyond its end.
>   References within the address range starting at pa and continuing for
>   len bytes to whole pages following the end of an object shall result
>   in delivery of a SIGBUS signal.

1. Yes, you can `mmap` length that is greater than the size of file, and
2. Access to any pages beyond the end of the file, except the last (possibly partial) page will result in `SIGBUS`.

Comment: Is this also true if I `mmap` a length greater than the size of file and such that an additional page is required?

Comment: @David I am sorry I don't quite understand. I thought I covered precisely your question. If the file is 8190 bytes in length, a page is 4096 bytes, and you mmap 3 pages, then access to bytes `[0..8191]` (second page extends 2 bytes past the end of the file) is ok, and access to the 3rd page (which does not cover any part of the file) produces `SIGBUS`.